# ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server not found

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have a seed project from which I have deleted the `node_modules` just for the sake of completeness before committing to source control (yes, I have a `.gitignore`).

Having then subsequently run `npm install`, I have discovered that there is no `.\node_modules\.bin` folder from which to launch the webpack dev server. This has previously worked fine. I have `"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"` in my `devDependencies`.

Anyone know why my `.bin` folder is not being created by npm?

Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `.\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\` folder also? If not, then you know it's failing to install completely rather than just installing the bin file.

`npm install` [should install every dependency in your `package.json` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), so something is up.

> npm install (in package directory, no arguments):
>
> Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.
>
> In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it
>   installs the current package context (ie, the current working
>   directory) as a global package.
>
> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as
>   dependencies in package.json.
>
> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable
>   is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in
>   devDependencies.

#### Firstly

I would first make sure that your npm config is not set to production. Run this command:

`npm config get production`

..and if it it returns true, then set it to false with:

`npm config set production false`

#### Secondly

If this fails, then create a new folder in a completely different location (even under a different hard drive or username) and set up your package.json file all over again (`npm init`, `npm install module`, `npm install module2 --save-dev`, and so on..). If this works, then perhaps npm is scaling your directory looking for certain dependencies, finding one somewhere, and therefore not installing it here.

#### Thirdly

Check your [npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) file. Run `npm config list` and make sure everything looks okay here (it's a long shot, however, something may be up).

#### Or..

If you do not want to do that, then it's possible to force an install of only the devDependencies with this command

`npm install --only=dev`

Good luck!

Comment: That should be a `.\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\ ` folder (without the `.bin`)